# image dataset for Comparison of SVM and CNN

Tags: neural-networks, svm, conv-neural-network

I'm looking for a suitable image dataset to train an SVM, a CNN and possibly an MLP as classifiers and to compare the results. Since an SVM archieves good results with small data sets and a CNN and above all an MLP requires a very long time for training with large datasets, this dataset should be rather smaller. But this search is quite difficult because the dataset should not be too big but not too small. The dataset should be suitable to train a CNN und possible even an MLP in the shortest possible time, I mean with GPU max. 1 day. It would probably be better if the image resolution is not too high. Since the features have to be extracted in advance in SVM, it would probably be better if the data is not too complex.

Regarding CNN, I know that there are the so-called pre-trained networks, but I am not sure if they are really suitable for such a comparison.

Does anyone have experience with it? I would be very grateful for any tip on a suitable dataset.

Comment: There's the standard [MNIST database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database).

Comment: Many Thanks. Yes, the MNIST database could be very interesting, but seems to be used very often. The above comparison could be a topic for my master thesis. Could the classification of trees using tree leaves be too time-consuming for the CNN and MLP if the leaves were photographed on a white or black background?